# Vertical scrolling on React Native Dropdowns

Tags: android, react-native, drop-down-menu, dropdown

My Android app built using React Native doesn't allow one to scroll a DropDownPicker (github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker).  What can be changed in the below code to fix this?  The parent components and relevant styles can be found below.  The code itself is also wrapped in a flex 1 container view.

```
 <View style = {styles.dropdownContainerIn}>
           <TextInput
             keyboardType = "number-pad"
             style = {styles.toAmount}
             placeholder="Amount"
             placeholderTextColor="white" 
             value = {text}
             editable = {false}
             maxLength = {18}
           />
           <DropDownPicker
             placeholder={from}
             open={openFrom}
             items={baseCurrencies}
             setOpen={setOpenFrom}
             onOpen={() => setOpenTo(false)}
             setItems={setBases}
             onSelectItem={(from) => {setFrom(from.label)}}
             style={styles.dropdown}
             textStyle={styles.dropdownText}
             dropDownContainerStyle={styles.dropdownOption}
             searchable = {true}
             searchPlaceholder="Search"
         />
    </View>


dropdown:{
   backgroundColor: "transparent",
   borderColor: 'white',
   borderWidth: 3,
   width: 120,
   height: 60,
   borderRadius: 3,
   flex: 1
 },
 dropdownText:{
   fontSize: 15,
   fontWeight: 'bold',
   color: 'white',
 },
 dropdownOption:{
  backgroundColor: '#123',
   borderColor: 'white',
   borderWidth: 2,
   width: 340,
   transform: [{translateX: -220}],
 },
 dropdownContainerIn:{
   flexDirection: 'row',
   transform: [{translateX: 140}, {translateY: 160}],
   marginRight: 20,
 },
 toAmount:{
   width: 220,
   height: 60, 
   borderColor: 'white',
   borderWidth: 3,
   borderRadiusLeft: 3,
   borderRightWidth: 0,
   color: 'white',
   fontSize: 20,
   paddingLeft: 15,
 },
```

Comment: Nothing at all. Test on other devices or it could be some problem with your code.

Comment: I think the issue is with my dropdown picker ()https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker) because I tested using a regular FlatList and it did work as expected.   Do you know what modifications can be done to the code above to fix this?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's the problem. Could be the styling, parent or sibling component, or any else. It would be better if you can provide more code.

Comment: I have added all the relevant code as an edit.

Comment: Please take a look at this https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/rules

Comment: For those encountoring this issue add this line of code underneath the import statements: DropDownPicker.setListMode("MODAL");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those encountering this issue add this line of code underneath the import statements: `DropDownPicker.setListMode("MODAL")`